# Как сделать фоновое изображение под размер видимой области на мобильном устройстве?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Когда открываешь сайт на мобильном устройстве, видно, что фоновое изображение зависит от количества контента на странице, там где его больше - фоновое изображение увеличивается, где меньше - уменьшается. Так например при открытии панели навигации на мобильном устройстве видно что фон резко увеличивается, так как панель раздвигается и становиться больше контента. Как сделать так, чтобы фон не зависел от количества контента, зависел только от области просмотра.

Что есть на данный момент в css и html

```
<body class="bg-image1">
body {  
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.bg-image1 {  
        background-image: url(путь); 
}
```

Comment: body{min-height:100vh;}

Comment: данное решение не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
background-position: top center;
```

Comment: все осталось без изменений

Comment: Есть возможность показать полный вариант? Подобной проблемы как у вас не наблюдаю.

Comment: В симуляторе мобильной версии в браузере все нормально, но вот когда заходишь с телефона все иначе

Comment: Развернул для примера https://protected-ocean-52184.herokuapp.com/ru/blog , заходите с мобильного устройства

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: Осталась единственная проблема, фон не перемещается при скролинге